Servlet error during deploy webapp on Wildfly 26.1.2
I'm trying to deploy my webapplication on Wildfly but i'm facing an error during startup. It seems something related to JAXRS but I cannot understand what i'm doing wrong...

    00:11:20,162 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."myApp.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "myApp.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet from [Module "deployment.myApp.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:414)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:255)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:105)
        at org.jboss.as.server@18.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet from [Module "deployment.myApp.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:200)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at org.jboss.as.jaxrs@26.1.2.Final//org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:412)
        ... 11 more
    
    00:11:20,202 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myApp.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"myApp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"myApp.war\"
        Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet from [Module \"deployment.myApp.war\" from Service Module Loader]
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet from [Module \"deployment.myApp.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}


Could you please support me?
I tried put the JAXRS library without success
EDIT:
Adding the web.xml where the servlet has been declared

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    
    
    
    <context-param><param-name>timestamp</param-name><param-value>2024</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>version</param-name><param-value>1.4.5</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>title</param-name><param-value>myApp</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>debugJsp</param-name><param-value>0</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name><param-value>message</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param><param-name>com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.ADD_STS_HEADER_WEBAPP</param-name><param-value>max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload</param-value></context-param>
    <filter><filter-name>NoCachingFilter</filter-name><filter-class>it.myApp.filter.NoCacheFilter</filter-class><init-param><param-name>maxAge</param-name><param-value>1200</param-value></init-param></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>NoCachingFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern><url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern><url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
    <filter><filter-name>CSPFilter</filter-name><filter-class>it.myApp.filter.CSPFilter</filter-class></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>CSPFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
    <filter><filter-name>httpLoggingFilter</filter-name><filter-class>it.myApp.web.filter.HttpLoggingFilter</filter-class></filter><filter-mapping><filter-name>httpLoggingFilter</filter-name><url-pattern>/*</url-pattern><url-pattern>/*/_login.jsp*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
    
    <listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
    <listener><listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class></listener>
    <listener><listener-class>it.myApp.web.listener.InitServletContextListener</listener-class></listener>
    <servlet><servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param><param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value></param-value></init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htmx</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/funzioni/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/amministrazione/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/news.jsp</url-pattern>
    
    </servlet-mapping>
    
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>test-myAppServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
    
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>test-myAppServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/myAppServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    
        <context-param>
          <param-name>properties_file</param-name>
          <param-value>myApp.properties</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <session-config><session-timeout>20</session-timeout></session-config>
    <welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
    <error-page><error-code>503</error-code><location>/503ErrorPage.jsp</location></error-page>
    <error-page><error-code>405</error-code><location>/errorPage.jsp</location></error-page>
    <error-page><error-code>404</error-code><location>/404ErrorPage.jsp</location></error-page>
    <error-page><error-code>400</error-code><location>/400ErrorPage.jsp</location></error-page>
    <error-page><exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type><location>/errorPage.jsp</location></error-page>
    <jsp-config>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/jstl-c</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/jstl-fmt-rt</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/fmt-rt.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/jstl-fn</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/fn.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/spring</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/spring-form</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-form.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/tiles-jsp.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    <taglib><taglib-uri>/tags/jstl-c-rt</taglib-uri><taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c-1_0-rt.tld</taglib-location></taglib>
    </jsp-config>
    </web-app>



My guess is you have it.myApp.web.servlet.myAppServlet defined somewhere in a web.xml. It would be helpful to see your web.xml.

hi! thank you! i've added the web.xml. Of course, the java class exists, so i cannot understand why i get ClassNotFoundException

Can you locate the file myAppServlet.class in the WAR file structure? One possible location is WEB-INF/classes/it/myApp/web/servlet. Capitalization matters (unless the war file is exploded in a Windows file system). OR it should be in a JAR under the WAR's WEB-INF/lib directory. Can you post if it is there and, if it s, where?

@NikosParaskevopoulos mmm...my WEB-INF/classes is empty. Maybe I need to configure something on VSCode in order to set the output there?

@NikosParaskevopoulos i made a change in the vscode settings in order to put the classes file under WEB-INF/classes. Now, the myAppServlet.class is under WEB-INF/classes/it/myApp/web/servlet but i'm getting the same error...

The important thing is where is this file when deploying in WildFly. Can you check the deployed WAR (unzip it) or the directory myApp.war (if deployed exploded)?

You don't really need that entry if you use the @WebServlet annotation. If you're seeing the same error though, then something in the packaging of your application seems wrong.
